# Binding DataSource of one ComboBox to SelectedValue of another

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I have two ComboBoxes `envelopeList` and `datasetList`. Consider the following line of code:

`envelopeList.DataBindings.Add("DataSource", datasetList, "SelectedValue");`

The intended functionality is to update `envelopeList.DataSource` to be `datasetList.SelectedValue` whenever the selection is changed. However, if `datasetList` is empty this throws an `ArgumentException` saying "Additional information: Complex DataBinding accepts as a data source either an IList or an IListSource."

I don't understand why this happens. When `datasetList` is empty `datasetList.SelectedValue` returns null and `envelopeList.DataSource = null` does not throw any exception. This doesn't throw any exceptions either: `envelopeList.DataSource = datasetList.SelectedValue;`, nor does this: `envelopeList.DataSource = new BindingSource(datasetList, "SelectedValue");`, even when `datasetList` is empty.

Doing the binding after `datasetList` has at least one item works as intended, until it becomes empty in which case `envelopeList.DataSource` isn't updated. The `DataSourceChanged` event isn't even fired. (Though in my case that noticed by the user since the DataSource will be emptied when the item in `datasetList` is deleted).

To make this work I have to execute the following code after `datasetList` has been populated for the first time:

```
if(doonce && !(doonce = false))
    envelopeList.DataBindings.Add("DataSource", datasetList, "SelectedValue");
```

It's a very ugly way to do it and I would much rather be able to do this during initialization.

---

**Some potentially important information.**

Both ComboBoxes are actually my own inheriting type `AdvancedComboBox`. This is the relevant functionality within:

```
public class AdvancedComboBox : ComboBox, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected override void OnSelectedValueChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSelectedValueChanged(e);
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedValue")); //I don't know why, but it works even if I remove this line.
    }
}
```

(I have other uses for the `PropertyChanged` event, even if I apparently don't actually need it for the `SelectedValue` property.)

`datasetList.DataSource` is bound to an `IBindingList` containing `DatasetPresenter` objects.
`DatasetPresenter` has a property `Areas` that return an `IBindingList` with the objects that I want `envelopeList` to show.
I run `datasetList.ValueMember = "Areas"` before doing the binding.

---

**The question**

How do I make `envelopeList.DataBindings.Add("DataSource", datasetList, "SelectedValue");` work even when `datasetList` is empty or achive a similar result?
I prefer solutions that I only have to execute during initialization of the ComboBoxes and/or code that I can put inside the `AdvancedComboBox` class so that it remains self-containing.

Bonus: Why doesn't it work when `datasetList` is empty? Even though `datasetList.SelectedValue` returns null and `envelopeList.DataSource = null` is okay.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a solution, but it's not pretty.

I created this class specifically for this purpose:

```
private class PlaceHolder
{
    public string Name { get; }//This property is the DisplayMember of both ComboBoxes.
    public List<PlaceHolder> Areas { get { return new List<PlaceHolder>(0); } }//This property is the ValueMember of datasetList.
}
```

And during initialization I run this code.

```
datasetList.DataSource = new List<PlaceHolder>() { new PlaceHolder() };
envelopeList.DataBindings.Add("DataSource", datasetList, "SelectedValue");
datasetList.DataSource = myController.Datasets;//This is the intended data source.
```

It's ugly and I'm still looking for better solutions.